# Keyboard not working in Windows Server 2016 Hyper-V, running inside Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, user-accounts, hyper-v-server-2016

I am considering to migrate my server to Windows Server 2016 Hyper-V. Currently I use Windows 10 with Oracle VirtualBox as HyperVisor. In order to test out Windows Server 2016 Hyper-V, I decided to create a new Virtual Machine and installed Windows Server 2016 Hyper-V.

All went well, and the installation completed. It starts, I get the command window showing that it is starting, then says that the password for the Administrator user needs to be changed. I can press ok and type the new password, but it does not understand the <kbd>enter</kbd> key, so I cannot confirm the password and continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me several days to figure it out.

Apparently, you need to use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to go to the other field, so you can type the password again, and then confirm with <kbd>enter</kbd>